# Testing the change of an element in componentDidUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a defect where I need to reset the scroll position of an element after new data has been loaded so the scroll is back at the top of the element. I handle the action in componentDidUpdate(), and manually the behavior works as expected. However, I am having trouble getting to write a successful test for it using enzyme and jest.

Here's a snippet of the component with what I think is the relevant items:

```
this.gridNode = null;

... 

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const node = this.getGridWrapperNode();
  if (!isEqual(this.props.data, prevProps.data) && (node && node.scrollTop > 0)) {
    node.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}

...

getGridWrapperNode = () => (
  this.gridNode && this.gridNode.getElementsByClassName('datagrid-grid-wrapper')[0]
);
```

and here is the test case:

```
  it('should reset gridWrapperNode scrollTop position if data has changed', () => {
    const mounted = mount(<Grid {...props} />);

    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('datagrid-grid-wrapper');
    element.scrollTop = 46;

    mounted.instance().gridNode = element;

    mounted.setProps({
      ...props,
      data: [{ val: 'ya' }],
    });

    const el = mounted.instance().gridNode;
    expect(el.scrollTop).toEqual(0);
  });
```

However, the test is always failing saying it expected the value to be 46, the originally set value. Am I not writing the test correctly that it is not updating and therefore the element's scrollTop is not getting set back to 0? Or is it something I'm doing in `componentDidMount()` ?

Comment: Is `componentDidUpdate` actually being called when you call `wrapper.update();`?

Comment: yeah, I accidentally left that wrapper.update() in there, as it is useless. I checked what props.data was equal to after the .setProps(), and it was reflecting the changes so I don't believe it was an issue with the component updating. I'll update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: What does `getGridWrapperNode()` do? It doesn't seem like it returns anything.

Comment: it returns that specific elment in the DOM, a div with the className `datagrid-grid-wrapper`

Comment: Could you put the entire function in the post? It looks cut off, so im confused

Comment: that is the entire function, you'll notice the closing paren is on the same line. i will update so you can see that is the entire function.

Comment: Hm okay, because it doesnt look like you're actually returning; there is no `return`.

Comment: the use of the arrow function along with the parens `funcName = () => ()` is an implicit return, so it is getting returned

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: What if instead of checking `el.scrollTop`, you check `element.scrollTop`